# An affine group behaving like a field

Tags: group-theory, model-theory

This question is about an example of interpreting a field in an affine group, from Section 1.3 of Marker's *Model theory: An introduction*.

Let $F$ be an infinite field and $G$ be the group of transformation of the form $x \mapsto ax + b$, where $a \in F^\times$ and $b \in F$ (write $T(a, b)$ for such a transformation).  The aim is to show that $F$, as a structure in the language of rings, is definably interpretable in $G$, as a structure in the language of groups.

It is easy to identify the subgroups of $G$ that are suitable for interpreting multiplication and addition, resp., namely:
$$
B := \{T(x, 0)\}\ \text{and}\ A := \{T(1, x)\}
$$

Then Marker makes two crucial points for the definability, by using group-theoretic devices.  The first is that the map $i:A \setminus \{1\}\rightarrow B$; $T(1, x) \rightarrow T(0, x)$ is definable by using the action of $B$ on $A$ by conjugation: $i(a) = b$ iff $bab^{-1} = \alpha$, where $\alpha = T(1, 1)$.  The second is that the subgroups $A$ and $B$ are also definable: they are the groups of elements that commutes with $\alpha$ and $\beta$, resp., where $\beta = T(\tau, 0)$ and $\tau \neq 0, 1$.

My question is how to come up with these facts.  I'm surprised by them because what I naturally want to define turn out to be just centralizers or a map obtained from conjugation.  Are these just ad-hoc arguments, or are there a general (group-theoretic) principles that make $i, A$ and $B$ definable?

Comment: I think the intuition behind this is related to Lie theory more than general group theory. In real case, $A,B$ are one-parameter subgroups, and the existence and definition of these things can probably be somewhat rigorously explained in terms of Lie algebra of $G$ (or more precisely, the infinitesimal generators of $A$ and $B$). My Lie theory is quite rusty, though, so I won't try to do that.